# how to convert image to responsive css code

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, base64

Recently, I noticed many websites are not using images for their logo and even for some content images. I am unable to copy those images or open images in a new tab.

When I checked in inspect elements those were codes, not real images.

Example:

**SVG**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="210" height="45" viewBox="0 0 286.2 58.1"><path d="M63,10.9c-4.4-7.2-14.1-3.1-12,5.2C53.8,27.3,67.4,30,72.4,40c2.7,5.4,1,10.9-3.2,13.3s-11.6,3.4-16.1.1c-2.3-1.6-2.1-2.8-3.3.3-.3,1-1,2.1-2.2,1s-1.9-6.9,1.4-9.1,3.5-.6,5.4,1.3c4.7,3.9,10.7,2.8,12.2-.4s0-5.3-2-7.6-7.4-6-11.2-10.4S44.7,16.3,47.2,9.9s8.3-10.7,15.6-7c4.3,2.2,8.5,7.2,6.1,12.1s-6.8,4.5-9.2,1,4.5-3.1,3.3-5.1Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M82,22.5c.2,6.2-6.8,5.7-7-.2A3.1,3.1,0,0,1,78.5,19a3.9,3.9,0,0,1,2.2,1A3.8,3.8,0,0,1,82,22.5Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M75.5,36.3h-.3c-2.9,1.7-2-1.7-.5-3.7s3-2.7,4.3-2.6a2.5,2.5,0,0,1,2.1,1.8c.8,3.9-3.5,14.9,1.1,17.7a2,2,0,0,0,2.7-.4c.8-1,1-2.7,2.1-3s.9,0,1,1.4c.4,3.9-1.4,9.5-6.7,7.6s-4.6-11.3-4.6-16.3c0-.3-.1-3.3-1.2-2.6Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M110,29.5a2.3,2.3,0,0,0-2.3-1.6c-2.6.2-3.1.1-5.6.2l-6.3.3c.4-3,.7-6,1-9,1-8.7,1-14.1.2-16.1s-1.7-2.1-3.2-1.8-2.7,4.3-3,11.6a152,152,0,0,0,.8,16.1l-3.2.9a14.2,14.2,0,0,0-2.6,1c-.4.2-.5.6-.5,1.2a4.5,4.5,0,0,0,.5,2c.8,2,2.2,5,4,9.2l3.6,8.3c1.1,2.6,2.5,3.8,4.3,3.8a4.5,4.5,0,0,0,2.5-.6c.3-.4.1-1.2-.4-2.5a39.3,39.3,0,0,1-3.1-10.7c-.3-1.8-.4-5.3-.5-8.4,5.5-1.2,9.3-.9,12.4-1.7h.2c1.2-.7.5-.3.9-.8S110.2,30,110,29.5Zm-16.5,17-.2.2h-.2a6.6,6.6,0,0,0-.5-1c-.3-.6-1.5-5-1.6-5.1s-1.1-4.1-1.3-4.5a1.4,1.4,0,0,1,0-.7,1.1,1.1,0,0,1,.4-.6,4.8,4.8,0,0,1,1.4-.6h.2v.4l.2.8.3,2.2,1,6.1.3,2.4Z" fill="#000"></path><path d="M129.1,48.7c-3.4,4.2-8.2,8-13.6,6.5-3-1.1-5-4.1-6-7.8a22.7,22.7,0,0,1-.2-11c1.2-5.5,4.6-10.1,8.5-10.2,7.4.8,11.2,8.9,7.4,14.7-2.1,3.2-6.5,4.9-8.6,5.9s-1.4.5-1.3,2.1c.3,3.7,6.6,3.7,10.6-4.6.4-.7,2.9-4,4.5-3,3.4,2-.9,6.8-1.3,7.4Zm-15.5-5.2c4.4-1.4,8-5.3,8.4-7.4.6-3.9-5.5-7.3-7.7-.8-.6,1.6-.8,5.3-.7,8.2Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M158.9,34.1c-.3,3.3,4.7,20.6,1.1,20.9s-3.5.4-4-.8,1.5-10-.2-7.3c-.4.6-.3.7-.9,1.8-6,10.7-14.1,7.8-18.8-.8a35.8,35.8,0,0,1-3.6-20.2c1.3-12.4,6.6-28.6,19.1-25.9,9.8,2.1,3,15.2-.4,11.8C143.1-4.1,127,38.7,144.8,49c5.2,3,9.6-6.7,8.5-11s-.9-3.1-2.4-2.7-5.1,3.8-6.2,2.8-2.2-6.4.6-6.6,5.1.9,8.9-3.7,6.3-2.9,5.7,1.6c-.3,2-.9,3.1-1,4.7Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M181.8,27.7a16,16,0,0,0-10.1-3c-5.5.6-10.5,4.2-10,9.9.2,2.5.5,12.9,1.4,17.2a4.1,4.1,0,0,0,2.6,3.2,3.2,3.2,0,0,0,3.8-1.6c.9-2.1-.1-4-.6-5.8-1.1-3.6-1.5-8.6-1.8-11.7-.6-6.4,9-7.2,11.3-3.5-1.6,2.5.8,4.1,3.7,1.8s1.6-5-.3-6.5Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M195,55.5c13.4-2.2,18.5-23,1.9-30.1-17.2-5.6-18.1,33.5-1.9,30.1Zm-6-16.7c1.5-16.4,12.3-8.8,13.6,1.9S186.7,57.5,189,38.8Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M214.3,34.2c-2.1,4.6-1.2,23.2,8.4,14.4,2-1.9,2.3-8.1,1.5-13.4-.2-1.2-1.2-4.9-1.5-6s.7-3.4,2.5-4a3.1,3.1,0,0,1,3.7,1.8c1,2.4.4,6.3.3,7.9-.4,4.7-1.1,10.6.6,13.7.7,1.3,1.7,1.4,1.7,2.4.2,3.5-4,5.8-5.6,3.6-.4-.6-.1-1.5-.7-2-7.9,7.1-16.6,1.6-16.5-8.6.1-2.2-.3-5.8.6-9s1-4.7,2.2-6,2.6-.5,3.1-.1.3,3.6-.3,5.3Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M249.6,50c1.4-4.8,3-12.6,2-15.5S244,28.6,241,33c-1.8,2.8-1.8,12.5.5,18.2.5,1.3-.5,3.2-2.2,3.8-6.6,2.2-1.5-16.1-5.4-21.9-.8-1.3-1.8-1.4-1.9-2.4-.4-3.3,3.6-5.5,5.3-3.4.5.6.2,1.5.9,1.9,7.3-6.7,18.2-1.7,18.9,8A40.6,40.6,0,0,1,254.5,52a10.3,10.3,0,0,1-1.7,3,2.2,2.2,0,0,1-3.1.1c-1.2-.9-.6-3.5-.1-5.1Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M278.7,28.7c.6-5.2-1.6-20.5-5.6-20.8-1.1-.1-1.4-2.8-.6-4.4s2.4-2,5.3-.8c4.7,1.9,5,19.3,5.1,24.6s-.1,11.3.7,16.1a20.3,20.3,0,0,0,1.3,4.5c.8,1.9,1.7,3.2,1.1,4.3s-4.8,3.3-6,2.1a7,7,0,0,1-1.4-4c-7,11.1-18,2.4-19.5-8.2s7.8-22.2,19.6-13.4ZM267.8,49.1c8.7,6.3,11.5-10.1,7.1-16.1s-18.8,7-7.1,16.1Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M13.2,45.3C6.4,43.1,1.5,36.5.4,29.6-2.9,10.4,17.4-6.9,37.8,2.7,38,7,36,13.2,30.5,15,57.8,32.2,34.5,67.3,6,55.8c-5.2-2.7-2.4-7.5,3.1-4.7s14.3,2.1,19.4-.7A22.7,22.7,0,0,0,36.8,43a28.5,28.5,0,0,0,1.9-3.6c.5-1,1.8-5.2.8-5.6s-.4.2-.5.5a19.2,19.2,0,0,1-3.9,7.3,19.5,19.5,0,0,1-8.4,5.8c-4.1,1.4-8.8,1.6-15.3.2a23.1,23.1,0,0,0,1.8-2.3ZM32,4.5s.1.7.2,1.8a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-3,7.5l-1.6,1.4c7.7,4.8,11.7,15.3,7.3,22.6-6.1,9.8-18,7.6-24.5.8s-5.9-16.1-1-22.9A28,28,0,0,1,32,4.5Z" fill="#97ca4f" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M8.8,26c1.5-14.6,18.3-17.4,24.5,2S6.5,43.7,8.8,26Zm13.7,9.6c13.3.5,6.9-13-1.8-16s-13.4,16,1.8,16Z" fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
```

**Base64**

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

**Pure CSS :** https://jsfiddle.net/L3k5n479/  (Due to only 30K letter limit in the question. I am unable to add here this 3rd code)

I tried making like siteground but writing own CSS in too hard. I googled and found some tools, but it is breaking the pixel or image colour. But these logos are perfect as image without any effect in clarity.

I have 4 questions

1. How to make like this. is there any free tool avaiable for better quality?
2. Is SVG is a CSS or it a different code?
3. What is the benefit of using codes instead of images?
4. what is best approach Pure CSS, SVG, Base64 or something other?

Comment: Don't sweat it, just use an SVG image!  `<img src = "logo.svg" alt="my company logo" />`

Answer (score 2):

1. Depends if you're asking about SVGs or Base64s really. You can find plenty of tools online to convert an image file to Base64 code but for an SVG you'll need to make it from scratch, it's not exactly an image, more of a set of instructions to draw a bunch of vectors (which will look good at any size, since they are not made of pixels like a normal image).
2. SVG is Scaled Vector Graphics. A set of instructions to draw shapes basically.
3. I have used Base64 image encoding before for a few things at work, where I want to be able to send one .html file and have everything in there, rather than needing to send a whole load of files. It's just another tool really, sometimes it's the right tool for the job.
4. Really, depends on what you're doing. Best approach is not universal.

Answer (score 2):

so basically you are asking, Base64 vs SVG vs Image vs CssImage

Well first of all, Base64 and CssImage are not that different from a normal image, the only difference is a normally images data is stored in a .png or .jpeg file whiles the base64 and CssImage are a bunch of text in your html, all in all they are the same thing, just a bunch of pixel data, There are two main categories of images.

- Pixel images ( Base64, Images, CssImages )
- Vector images ( SVG )

Just so you know, there is HtmlSVG where you see the svg codes directly in the html file. ( check this website for a snippet https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_inhtml.asp )

Vector images are mathematically defined, hence they generally are( 90% of the time ) very small in size hence your websites load faster and consume less data, and they produce sharp images, so where ever you can use an svg, use it.
SVG's are best used for logos and extremely simple images, so to answer your questions :

1. Yes there are many tools you can use to make svgs, you can use Inkscape (i personally use inkscape) which is free, or you can use Adobe Illustrator, this site has a list of Vector image tools [https://windowsreport.com/vector-graphics-software/#:~:text=Adobe%20Illustrator%20Adobe%20Illustrator%20is%20the%20most%20popular,it%20offers%20a%20wide%20range%20of%20advanced%20features](https://windowsreport.com/vector-graphics-software/#:%7E:text=Adobe%20Illustrator%20Adobe%20Illustrator%20is%20the%20most%20popular,it%20offers%20a%20wide%20range%20of%20advanced%20features).
2. Svg is its own thing, it is not a part of css, but it works with css, people use svg in other things appart from web developments, svgs can be used to define the tool path for a 3d printer,so svg is a big thing on its own.
3. if you are using CssImage or Base64 codes, the only advantage is that everything comes in one big html file, but note that this can cause your webpages to load slowly, because the html file itself is big, you have an entire image in there, its advantageous to separate the images from the html codes in big projects, for small projects you can go ahead. SVG is a different beast, and has huge advantages when used in the proper areas.
4. Best approach, i will say use SVG where ever you can, and if you have to use an image, dont use css or embedded base64 images, note that I am speaking from a point of view where your project is going to expand over time and maybe your website serves over 10000 users.

- Using an image file is straightforward, any new developer you hire can easily read your code and understand what is going on.
- Base64 and Cssimage require a lot of text, that means if i am scrolling through your html to make changes to your website, i have scroll through all that text, its more convenient to put it in a separate file .... like an image file.
- That is not the purpose of css and html attributes, css is supposed to style your html not define images, hence css was created and optimized for styling html not defining images, same for html tags, they define the structure of your webpages, they are not meant for defining your images, so for the sake of using them for what they were built for, i will suggest you use normal image files and SVG files as opposed to embedding them into the HTML and CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recently many websites are using SVG logos, SVG icon for High-Quality Purposes you can resize them to any size without any damage to the image.

So instead of images try to use SVG.

For Example - Some of the popular Free SVG Download Websites:

https://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/free-svg
https://pixabay.com/images/search/svg/

And Also, if You want to convert your image to CSS, Try some online tools.
like the [image to CSS online converter](https://imagetocss.com/), in which you can convert your image to CSS and also Basecode64.